# How to calculate solutions for logarithmic equations in python via sympy

Tags: python, sympy, physics

I try to find the friction factor for Moody diagram (f) by this formula using sympy

```
from sympy import *
f = Symbol ('f')
Re = 3000
relative_roughness=0.1
solve(f**(-0.5)+2*log(relative_roughness/3.7+2.51/(Re*(f)**(0.5)), 10), domain=S.Reals)
```

But the program finishes with error NotImplementedError: multiple generators [log(1/37 + 836666666666667/(1000000000000000000*sqrt(f))), sqrt(f)]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation 2*log(1/37 + 836666666666667/(1000000000000000000*sqrt(f)))/log(10) + 1/sqrt(f)

It works when relative_roughness=0, but I need more than 0. Please, help. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use sympy's `nsolve` function. Here with an initial guess of `0.1`:

```
In [29]: eq = f**(-0.5)+2*log(relative_roughness/3.7+2.51/(Re*(f)**(0.5)), 10)                                                    

In [30]: nsolve(eq, f, 0.1)                                                                                                       
Out[30]: 0.106947153535321
```